# DNS redirect of a url to another url

Tags: dns, redirect

We are currently looking at identifying the best approach to carry out a redirection of a url folder to another url folder o a separate domain.  We have tried a few options but have been unable to make this work.  Any other redirection options such as apache, html etc are not possible.  This url is only accessed through the browser by an application to download some files. This application cannot be changed but needs to download these files from another location.

Hence, we need to redirect the following:

> https://sub1.domain1.com/xyz

to

> https://sub2.domain2.com/abc/xyz

Any ideas how we can achieve this?

Note: we have full control of DNS of the domain1 and there are no plans to use this domain.

Comment: Why dont you just replace domain 1 for domain 2 if you have no intentions to use domain1?

Comment: domain1 will in fact be replaced with domain2 however the application will still keep looking at domain1 (until it updates) - hence we need to find a way how to 'redirect' the application to domain2 when it pings domain1

Comment: As @Jonathon Reinhart wrote i dont think it is possible to redirect in the DNS.
That is the job of the HTTP service you can do it on Apache for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with DNS alone. The DNS never sees the "path" part of the URL. You need a webserver aware of the situation who can provide a 302 redirect.